# In Haskell (max 3 5) * 2 => 10

Tags: haskell

This is my first day with Haskell, Can you please explain, how this works.

I assume, first the compiler should work on finding the max value among 3 and 5 and then multiply the result by 2.

Whereas, Haskell multiplies 5*2 and compare the result with 3 and finding the max.

Comment: `max (3 5) * 2` isn't 10, it's a type error because `3` isn't a function. I don't understand anything else in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Syntax**

```
max (3 5) * 2
```

This doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.  In the above, the function `3` is applied to the argument `5`.  Consider instead:

```
(max 3 5) * 2
```

Or equivalently:

```
max 3 5 * 2
```

**Terminology**

Let's also keep the terminology straight: the compiler doesn't perform any evaluation, it just produces binaries.

**Answer**

The first thing to consider is the function `*`.  There is no guaranteed order of evaluation here. To evaluate `max 3 5` the `max` function is applied to each argument and the results is `5`.  The second argument, `2` is already in normal form.  So now we just have `5*2` which produces `10`.

Answer (score 4):

You have your parentheses inexplicably backwards.

> Haskell multiplies 5*2 and compare the result with 3 and finding the max.

so you want

```
max 3 (5 * 2)
```

---

Your code as written tries to coerce the literal `3` into a function `Num a => a -> b`, then apply `5` to it. It can't do that, of course, so it stops.